# Проблема с циклом c++

Tags: c++

Имеется такой код

Никак не могу понять, в чем проблема. Пытался сделать цикл диалога с пользователем, при выборе пункта 1 - ничего, при 2 - вечный цикл. Винил внутренние функции, но они проверены, исправны на 100%. В чем может быть проблема?

```
void text::user_iteration()
    {
        int x;
        for( ;; )
        {
            std::cout << "--Menu--\n"
                << "Push the number to choose the option.\n"
                << "1. Add a string or few strings.\n"
                << "2. Check current text.\n"
                << "3. Exit.\n";
            if( std::cin >> x )
            {
                if( x == 1 )
                {
                    std::cout << "Enter your text please: \n";
                    text::add_string();
                    continue;
                }
                if( x == 2 )
                {
                    std::cout << "The current text is: \n";
                    text::output_text();
                    continue;
                }
                if( x == 3 )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Единственное, что работает верно, это 3.

Comment: А отладчик вы зачем не используете?

Comment: Хороший вопрос)

Comment: Либо я туплю, либо ничего путного от отладчика не получаю

Comment: Ответ на вопрос про или - однозначно ДА. Учитесь пользоваться отладчиком, без него не стоит и пытаться программировать.

Comment: @Freddy  Подготовьте минимальный компилируемый проверяемый пример, который воспроизводит проблему. Гадать здесь никто не будет. Я могу лишь предположить, что возникла ошибка ввода, в одной из вызываемых функций, а потому получается бесконечный цикл.

Comment: А не лучше ли вышеприведенные блоки кода, соответствующие пункту меню, завернуть в отдельные ф-ии, которые после того, как отработают, вызвают ф-ию menu ?

Comment: Действовал согласно последнему совету. Выяснил, что когда вызываю add_string внутри другой функции, add_string просто напросто проскакивает

Comment: Самое интересное, что если вызвать add_string в main, то она работает как того и ожидал

Comment: @Freddy, а как узнали, что проскакивает ? Отлаживали по шагам с заходом или без ?

Comment: По шагам с заходом. Почему-то при вызове функции add_string из menu есть только вход и выход из add_string

Comment: Причем дебаггер виснет на потоке ввода значения 1 2 или 3

Comment: Да, обнаружил, что при пошаговой отладке вызов add_string проскакивает, даже не заходя в саму эту функцию

Comment: Всё нормально [отрабатывает](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4jao9S9tld74EjDv). Попробуйте пересборку проекта с очисткой.

Comment: Вы мой ответ смотрели? Посмотрите - там вам все расписано...

Answer (score 3):

Почему не `case` используешь?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x;
    bool looping = true;
    char text[80];

    for( ;; )
    {
        if (!looping) break;
        std::cout << "--Menu--\n"
            << "Push the number to choose the option.\n"
            << "1. Add a string or few strings.\n"
            << "2. Check current text.\n"
            << "3. Exit.\n";
        std::cin >> x;
        switch(x)
        {
            case  1:
            {
                std::cout << "Enter your text please: \n";
                std::cin >> text;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                std::cout << "The current text is: \n";
                std::cout << text << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                looping = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я только что обнаружил проблему. вызов работает успешно, если не использовать этот длинный std::cout << с записями по меню. Я вообще в тупике. Даже вообразить не могу, почему так.

Comment: и case использовал, просто выложил свой последний вариант. 4 часа уже бьюсь с этим и понять не могу, в чем проблема.

Comment: самое смешное, что без std::cout все работает

Comment: Делайте отступ на 4 символа - и будет всё выглядеть кодом (строчка int main), либо выделите текст и нажмите иконку "код"

Comment: а зачем for?? когда можно было do while??

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку вот такой код работает корректно:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int x;
    for( ;; )
    {
        std::cout << "--Menu--\n"
            << "Push the number to choose the option.\n"
            << "1. Add a string or few strings.\n"
            << "2. Check current text.\n"
            << "3. Exit.\n";
        if( std::cin >> x )
        {
            if( x == 1 )
            {
                std::cout << "Enter your text please: \n";
                cout << "text::add_string()" << endl;
                continue;
            }
            if( x == 2 )
            {
                std::cout << "The current text is: \n";
                cout << "text::output_text();" << endl;
                continue;
            }
            if( x == 3 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

остается сделать вывод, что проблема в ваших функциях добавления строки и вывода. Без их текста говорить о чем-либо совершенно бессмысленно.

Как теперь принято говорить, *вангую* остатки в буфере ввода после чтения чисел.

Скорее всего у вас в `add_string` **не сбрасывается** буфер `cin` после ввода значения `x`; в буфере лежит `\n`, и вы получаете совсем не то, что хотели. А при запросе меню `x` считывается строка, а не число, и уходит в бесконечный цикл - вы же ошибки ввода не отрабатываете!

Comment: Вы правы, именно в этом проблема и заключалась! Спасибо!